# Separable generating function of a pair of dependent discrete random variables

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, generating-functions, moment-generating-functions

Independence is **sufficient** but **not necessary** for the generating function of the sum of two random variables to be the product of their individual generating functions.

I am trying to come up with an example of two dependent rv's whose joint generating function is the product of the individual generating functions.

I have tried U:=X+Y and V:=X-Y where U and V are dependent but X and Y aren't. I ended up with $[\phi(t)]^2$ vs $\phi(t^2)$

Generating function $\phi_{X}(t) := \sum_{k = 0}^\infty Pr\{X=k\} t^k$

Comment: By "generating function" do you mean "moment generating function"?

Comment: Generating function $\phi_{X}(t) := \sum_{k = 0}^\infty Pr\{X=k\} t^k$

Comment: Oh, so you're assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are nonnegative integer-valued? That wasn't clear at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a necessary and sufficient condition (in the case of the joint generating function). Let $X$ and $Y$ have joint generating function
$$\phi_{X,Y}(s,t) = \sum_{i,j=0}^\infty \mathbb P(X=i,Y=j)s^i t^j.$$
The product of the marginal generating functions is
$$
\begin{align*}
\phi_X(s)\phi_Y(t) &= \left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty\mathbb P(X=i)s^i\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty\mathbb P(Y=j)t^j\right)\\
&= \sum_{i,j=0}^\infty \mathbb P(X=i)\mathbb P(Y=j)s^it^j.
\end{align*}
$$
If we assume these are equal, then $$\mathbb P(X=i,Y=j)=\mathbb P(X=i)\mathbb P(Y=j)$$ for all $i,j\geqslant 0$, so $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

However, it is not the case that
$$ \phi_{X,Y}(s,s) = \phi_X(s)\phi_Y(s)$$ implies that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. This is a subtle distinction, but $\phi_{X,Y}(s,s)$ is the generating function of $X+Y$, not the *joint* generating function of $(X,Y)$.

For a counterexample, let $X$ and $Y$ each be uniformly distributed over $\{0,1,2\}$, with joint distribution

$$
\mathbb P(X=i,Y=j) = \begin{cases}
\frac19,& (i,j)\in\{(0,0), (1,1), (2,2)\}\\
\frac29,& (i,j)\in\{(0,2), (1,0), (2,1)\}\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $$\phi_X(s)\phi_Y(s)=\frac13(1+s+s^2)\frac13(1+s+s^2) = \frac1{9}(1+s+s^2)^2$$ and
$$
\begin{align*}
\phi_{X,Y}(s,s) &= \frac19 + \frac29 s + \frac39 s^2 + \frac29 s^3 +\frac19 s^4\\
&= \frac19(1 + 2s + 3s^2 + 2s^3 + s^4)\\
&= \frac19(1+s+s^2)^2\\
&= \phi_X(s)\phi_Y(s).
\end{align*}
 $$
But $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, as for example
$$\mathbb P(X=0)\mathbb P(Y=1)=\frac19\ne0=\mathbb P(X=0,Y=1).$$

Comment: The question is based on  Karlin &Taylor's A First Course In Stochastic Processes (Ch 1, Q 11.b, pg 39): Give an example of jointly distributed random variables X,Y which are not independent, but for which $\phi_{X,Y}(t,t) = \phi_{X}(t)\phi_{Y}(t)$ for all t. I am trying to construct such an example.

Comment: That is not exactly what you asked in the question ;)

Comment: From my original question: "I am trying to come up with an example of two dependent rv's whose joint generating function is the product of the individual generating functions." The first sentence was more of a background info and the last sentence was what I have tried before posting.

Comment: I was being nitpicky. Your original question referenced the *joint* generating function, i.e. that of $(X,Y)$. What you're actually interested in is the generating function of $X+Y$. These are two entirely different things. Nevertheless, I answered your question. It was trickier than I thought ;)

Comment: Moreover the original question from the book I mentioned before also says: " $\phi_{X,Y}(t,t)$ is the generating function of the sum X+Y. Thus independence is **sufficient** but **not necessary** for the generating function of a sum of random variables to be the product of the marginal generating functions."

Comment: Thanks, that is the example I was looking for. My "Reputation" does not allow for an up-vote, so I all can do to give credit is "accept this answer". Scratch that, I am allowed to up-vote. Also getting a "chat" warning!

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you. Look at the first part of the problem for why I am being so particular about distinguishing the generating function of $(X,Y)$ with $X+Y$ - the result is different. Thanks and welcome to MSE!